# Can't view private files

Tags: xiaomi

Once I move a few photos to private (by using the built-in OS feature of performing the drag-down gesture in the built-in File Manager and accessing the private files), and I try opening them in the listing, I am just prompted again for a password and then nothing happens. I was expecting the gallery to open up the photo but that doesn't happen. The only way out is to remove them out of the private listing, which defeats the purpose of having private files. Also, it keeps prompting me for a password *every time* I tap on a single file which is not something I'd want.

Phone: Xiaomi 12 Pro
OS: Xiaomi Mi UI 14